# Is it possible to programmatically fill input fields on a webpage through Windows Phone 7, and then save the output image?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, barcode

I'm trying to find a free online service that will generate a barcode image for me, when I enter the number (UPC, etc). So far I have only found this site:

http://www.barcoding.com/upc/

and they don't really have an api. They do have a form on that page, and I was wondering if there was a way my windows phone app could programmatically enter information into the form, and then show the resulting image on the phone screen. The page does list the the barcode generator as "a free service", and I would not be averse to giving them props in my app.

On further inspection, it looks like a javascript function is calling an asp file, like so:

```
var cp = new cpaint();
...
cp.call('buildbarcode.asp', 'BuildBarcode', BuildBarcodeCallback, barcode, symbology, fileFormat);
```

Would it be fair (or even possible) to call buildbarcode.asp directly from my app? Is there an equivalent of cpaint for c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be easier to generate the barcodes in your application.  There are a number of open source barcode tools at [codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=barcode&ac=8).  There's even one there for reading barcodes with the Wp7 camera.

Comment: thanks for the pointer. i understand that this was the wrong approach to my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if there's something to fill in the fields and take a screenshot, but you might be able to use something like this library for generating barcodes:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/BarcodeLibrary.aspx

Comment: This is a great library, but does not work for the phone as it was not compiled against Silverlight. Do you know of any alternatives, perhaps?